# Troubleshooting multiple GET variables In PHP

Tags: php, get, httprequest

This may be a very simple question but I don't what's the wrong thing am doing here...

To explain you clearly, I've set a real simple example below:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="test.php?link1=true">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="test.php?link2=true">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="test.php?link3=true">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['link1'])) {
        if(($_GET['link1']) == 'true') {
            echo 'This Is Link 1';
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['link2'])) {
        if(($_GET['link2']) == 'true') {
            echo 'This Is Link 2';
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['link3'])) {
        if(($_GET['link3']) == 'true') {
            echo 'This Is Link 3';
        }
    }
?>
```

This is a test.php page, here I've set 3 different arguments for $_GET, and show contents accordingly, now everything works perfect, the only thing am not understanding is how to block this kind of url say

if user clicks on link 1 the url will be :

```
http://localhost/test.php?link1=true
```

And the Output of this url is **This is Link 1**

Now if I change this url to :

```
http://localhost/test.php?link3=true&link2=true&link1=true
```

And the Output what I get is **This Is Link 1This Is Link 2This Is Link 3**

Now this is ok here, but it's very annoying if someone types this and see's forms one below the other, any way I can stop this tampering?

Comment: u can else if, so the first statement with the right conditions will be executed, and the rest not....

Comment: @TWCrap & Touki Thank's that works, I knew I was missing out something really small thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use elseif instead of seperate if statements. That way, only one will be executed (the first condition to be found true).

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['link1'])) {
    if(($_GET['link1']) == 'true') {
        echo 'This Is Link 1';
    }
} elseif(isset($_GET['link2'])) {
    if(($_GET['link2']) == 'true') {
        echo 'This Is Link 2';
    }
} elseif(isset($_GET['link3'])) {
    if(($_GET['link3']) == 'true') {
        echo 'This Is Link 3';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think using elseif is more appropriate. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 2):

A more robust way would probably be to use the same parameter name for each link, but vary the values. e.g.

```
<a href="test.php?link=link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="test.php?link=link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="test.php?link=link3">Link 3</a>
```

This way, even if anybody does specify multiple values in the query string only one of them will be used.

Comment: +1 this is a good alternative depending on the wider application.

Comment: Nice 1 bro~this is actually a perfect way and more clean... +1

Answer (score 0):

You are using consecutive `if` statements, so all the cases can be met and all the output can be echoed.

```
if(isset($_GET['link3'])) {
    if(($_GET['link3']) == 'true') {
        echo 'This Is Link 3';
    }
}
// Nothing stops the next if working here.
```

You could look into a switch statement instead and checking for the first one - or using the same `?link=` and passing different data to it in each link so that only one `if` statement can be met.